# Proof: lim of the nth root of n = 1

Tags: proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Let $ a_{n} :=  \sqrt[n]{n},\forall n\in Z^{+}$.
Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n} = 1$

Hint: Put $a_{n}-1$ in Part(1)

We had to proof before that $(1+a)^{n}\geq$${n}\choose{2}$$a^{2},\forall n\geq2$, using the binomial theorem

*My take at this was:*
Let $\epsilon>0, N>?, n>N$

$|a_{n} - a| <\epsilon\Leftrightarrow|\sqrt[n]{n}-1|<\epsilon$, which gives us: $(1+\epsilon)^n>n$

So now we want to show: $(1+\epsilon)^n>n$

*Using:*
$(1+a)^{n}\geq$${n}\choose{2}$$a^{2}$ with: ${n}\choose{2}$=$\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} =\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

We get:

$(1+\epsilon)^{n}\geq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\epsilon^{2}>(n-1)\frac{\epsilon^2N}{2}$

So *iff* $\frac{\epsilon^2N}{2}>1$ then $\frac{\epsilon^2N}{2}>1\Leftrightarrow N>\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}$, thus we'll get:

$(n-1)\frac{\epsilon^2N}{2}>(n-1)\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}=(n-1)$, so in conclusion:

$(1+a)^{n}>(n-1)$

Is this the right take? I know this should be a simpler thing to do, but we just started with this topic, and I think i missed smth while doing my steps. Any kind of feedback is appreciated ^^

Comment: So you know that $\sqrt[n]{n} \ge 1$. And maybe I'm missing the point of what you are calculating here, but what you want is an *upper bound*: $b_n \ge \sqrt[n]{n}$ with $b_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's continue from the inequality you have obtained using binomial theorem.

Since $n\ge2$, $n-1\ge \frac{n}{2}$
$$
a^n \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}(a-1)^2 \ge \frac{n^2}{4} (a-1)^2
$$
substituting $a \to \sqrt[n]{n}$:
$$
n \ge \frac{n^2}{4} (\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2 \\
\sqrt[n]{n}-1\le\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
thus, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N=[\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}]+1$, such that
$$
n > N \ \implies|\sqrt[n]{n}-1| < \epsilon.
$$